# postgres SKIP LOCKED not working

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Below the steps I followed to test the `SKIP LOCKED`:

1. open one sql console of some Postgres UI client
2. Connect to Postgres DB
3. execute the queries

   ```
   CREATE TABLE t_demo AS
   SELECT         *
   FROM            generate_series(1, 4) AS id;
   ```

check rows are created in that table:

```
TABLE t_demo
```

select rows using below query:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM t_demo 
 WHERE id = 2 
 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

it is returning results as 2

Now execute the above query again:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_demo 
WHERE id = 2 
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

this second query should not return any results, but it is returning results as  2

Comment: you have not opened any transaction when locking that row so the lock goes away immediately

Comment: You probably have autocommit enabled, so each statement is automatically committed and thus the locks are released. How exactly you change that depends on "some Postgres UI client" .

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE

> To prevent the operation from waiting for **other transactions** to
>   commit, use either the NOWAIT or SKIP LOCKED option

(emphasis mine)

if you run both queries in one window - you probably either run both in one transaction (then your next statement is not other transaction" or autocommiting after each statement (default)((but then you commit first statement transaction before second starts, thus lock released and you observe no effect